# Neo4j - calculate & set node property based on relation property

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I want to know, if it's possible to calculate & set (update) a node property based relation properties (incoming&outgoing)?
In my example, I would like to calculate an user personal "strength factor" (Kind of average) based on his relationships duration (int) divided by the count (int).

Thanks for your help in advance,

Cheers

Comment: It would help if you showed us your data model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The only trick is that you have to use [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-with) to first perform the aggregation (for calculating the average):

```
MATCH (n)-[r:RELTYPE]->()
WITH n, avg(r.duration) AS strength
SET n.strength = strength
```