# Neo4j - calculate & set node property based on an aggregation of node property

Tags: neo4j, properties, set

My issue is slightly different from this question: [Neo4j - calculate & set node property based on relation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649043/neo4j-calculate-set-node-property-based-on-relation-property). What I need to do is set a node property community size "CommSize" by counting the number of nodes that have the same "community" (which is another node property).  I have tried the following code, but it sets '1' for every "CommSize" and I know that I have communities with hundreds of nodes:

```
MATCH (i)
WITH i, i.community as comm, count(i) as CommCount
SET i.CommSize = CommCount;
```

How do I set the community size property with the count of nodes in each community?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you aggregate, the non-aggregation variables become the grouping key. So in your case, you have a single node per row `i`, and the count of that single `i` node, as well as that single node's community value.

To aggregate over all nodes, you need to either eliminate or aggregate `i` so it does not remain as a grouping key at the point of the aggregation.

You could try something like this:

```
MATCH (i)
WITH i.community as comm, count(i) as CommCount, collect(i) as nodes
FOREACH (i IN nodes |
 SET i.CommSize = CommCount);
```

If you have many nodes to process (> 50k perhaps) then you may want to look at batching your updates, such as with `apoc.periodic.iterate()` from APOC Procedures.